# SQL for finding second highest

Tags: sql

say I have a table of Employees where I maintain the name of the employee in one column and the salary drawn by them in another. what SQL should I write to find the name of the employee drawing the second highest salary???

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value

Comment: Which RDBMS are you use?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297160/sql-command-for-finding-the-second-highest-salary?rq=1). Pretty simple query, really.

Comment: @Hamlet: Not using any particular RDBMS. This was an interview question that I was asked. Generally I use MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from employees e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1
```

Others have mentioned the `limit`/`top`/`rownum` approach:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*
      from employees e
      order by salary desc
      limit 2
     ) t
order by salary
limit 1
```

You can do the same thing with offset:

```
select e.*
from employees e
order by salary desc
limit 2, 1
```

However, *all* of these have a problem if you have a tie for the highest salary.  The first method is easily fixed by replacing `row_number()` with `dense_rank()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from employees e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1
```

And, another method is:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.salary < (select max(salary) from employees)
order by salary desc
limit 1  -- or top 1 or rownum = 1 etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try selecting from "Top 2", sorted ascending, followed by a "Top 1" which should give you the correct row.

Comment: Wouldn't top 2 sorted ascending give you the two lowest salaries?

Comment: Check that... DESCENDING!  thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
select * from (select * from Employees order by salary desc limit 2) as A order by salary asc limit 1;
```