# SQL query to find Nth highest salary

Tags: sql, database

I am referring to following query to find Nth highest salary of a employee.

```
select sal from emp t where &n = (select count(sal) from (select distinct sal 
 from emp) where t.sal<=sal);
```

One gentleman said this query works. Could someone please explain how equating a COUNT ( which really will be value between 1 to X where X is total distinct salaries) to &n produce this result ?

I am trying to understand how database handles this query internally and produces result ?

Thank you.

Comment: Query should be like this. `select sal from emp t where &n = (select count(sal) from (select distinct sal 
 from emp where t.sal<=sal) AS x);`

Comment: Definitely, the key here is understanding that it's a correlated query which can be confusing to newcomers to SQL. I liked the explanation given here as well since it's extremely thorough: [Find nth highest salary - SQL](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the query will return the `nth` **lowest** salary value. To return the `nth` highest salary value you must change `t.sal <= sal` to `t.sal >= sal`.

Next, this query works by first finding the distinct list of salary values as one derived table and then determines the number of employees that have a salary less than each one in this list. `t.sal <= sal` is taking the derived table (which most databases would require have an alias) and comparing each value against the outer `emp` table. It should be noted that this will return multiple rows in the case of a tie.

To manually trace the output, we need some inputs:

```
Alice       | 200
Bob         | 100
Charlie     | 200
Danielle    | 150

Select Distinct sal
From emp
```

Gives us

```
200
100
150
```

Now we analyze each row in the outer table

```
Alice - There are 3 distinct salary values less than or equal to 200
Bob - 1 rows <= 100
Charlie - 3 rows <= 200
Danielle - 2 row <= 150
```

Thus, for each salary value we get the following counts (and reordered by count):

```
Bob 1
Danielle 2
Charlie 3
Alice 3
```

The most important aspect that I think you are overlooking is that the outer `emp` table is *correlated* to the inner count calculation (which is why it is called a correlated subquery). I.e., for each row in the outer `emp` table, a new count is calculated for that row's salary via `t.sal <= sal`. Again, most database systems would require the inner most query to have an alias like so (note the `As Z` alias):

```
Select sal
From emp As t
Where &n =  (
            Select Count(Z.sal)
            From    (
                    Select Distinct sal
                    From emp
                    ) As Z
            Where t.sal <= Z.sal
            )
```

Comment: Thanks.  However , its still not clear to me how following part will work ?

where &n = (select count(sal) from.....)

Wouldn't COUNT just return a number ? How it helps to select that particular row ?

Comment: @Vishal - Look at how the very last results pan out. The count of distinct salary values `<= 100` for `Bob` will be 1, Danielle: 2, Charlie: 3 and Alice: 3. Thus if you filter for say `n = 2`, you will get the `nth` **lowest** salary value. To get the `nth` **highest** salary value, you must change `t.sal <= sal` to `t.sal >= sal`

Comment: @Vishal - The inner query doing the `Select Count` is correlated to the outer query via `t.sal <= sal`. The `t.` part references the `emp` table in the outer most query. The `sal` part (without `t.`) references the inner query. Most RDMS would require that the derived table (starting with `Select Distinct Sal`) be aliased. (e.g. `(Select Distinct From emp) As Z`

Comment: @Vishal - Also remember that `&n` is your desired ranking (e.g., 1,2,3). Since the each row in the outer `emp` table is correlated to the count that is calculated (via `t.sal <= sal` ), for each employee we get their rank and determine if it matches the desired rank.

Comment: @Serious - It depends on what you mean by "all" databases. Certainly, this solution should work on all database products going back 20 years. The only features required are `Count(<field>)`, `Distinct` and subqueries. Ideally, you'd use ranking functions but support for ranking functions and `Rank` is not universal. MySQL for example does not support ranking functions.

Answer (score 1):

To get the nth highest salary value just put the value of 'N'.

```
Select Min(Salary) From (Select Top N * From Table_Name Order by Salary Desc);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sal 
from (
  select sal, 
         dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as rnk
) t
where rnk = 5;
```

Replace `where rnk = 5` with whatever "nth" you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT Max(Salary) as Salary
    FROM employee
    where  Salary Not in 
    (SELECT TOP N Salary FROM employee ORDER BY Salary DESC)
  where N is defined by you.
```

So let's say you have the following salaries in the table employee:
Here employeeID and Salary are the columns of employee table.

### EmployeeID  Salary

```
 101  25,000
 154  89,000
 987  42,000
 450  12,000
 954  50,000
```

If we want to see the fourth-highest salary

### Salary

```
25,000
```

Query return fourth highest salary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP n salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY salary DESC) a
ORDER BY salary
where n > 1 (n is always
```

Answer (score 0):

In the database record data  entries like

```
employ_id    NAME     salary
101          Henry    24000
102          Smith    24000
105          Roy      17000  
106          Robbin   15000 
702          Mac      2500
708          Bill     2100
709          Kane     2000
710          Ted      2000
```

here Some of employees having same salary then how to calculate nth (highest/lowest)salary

for the calculation of 3rd highest salary

```
select * from emloyees where salary in (select salary from (select rownum rank , salary from (select distinct salary from employees order by salary **desc**)) where rank =3;
```

---

```
ans = 15000
```

similarly to calculate 3rd lowest salary
Type same Query with a small change instead of desc type asc

```
select * from emloyees where salary in (select salary from (select rownum rank , salary from (select distinct salary from employees order by salary **asc**)) where rank =3;
```

Hope This will help you

Answer (score 0):

Change nth highest salary value just put the value of 'N'

```
SELECT e1.EmployeeName, e1.EmployeeSalary from Employee e1
where N = (
select COUNT(e2.EmployeeSalary) from Employee e2 where e2.EmployeeSalary >= e1.EmployeeSalary)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to achieve this:-

1)

```
 Select Top(1) sal from emp 
    where sal not in (select DISTINCT top(n-1) sal from emp order by sal desc)
```

2)

```
select salary     
          from (
           select salary,
           roe_number() over (order by salary ) as row from emp
          ) emp1
  where row= n;
```

- This query will not work if multiple rows have the same values one after another.

3)

```
select salary     
              from (
               select salary,
               dense_rank() over (order by salary ) as row from emp
              ) emp1
      where row= n;
```

- This will create a unique row number for all unique salary amounts.

4)

```
 Select Min(sal) From 
       (Select DISTINCT Top n * From emp Order by sal Desc)as emp1;
```

5)

```
   SELECT * FROM emp Emp1
            WHERE (n-1) = (
                             SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Sal))
                             FROM emp Emp2
                             WHERE Emp2.Sal > Emp1.Sal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select salary 
from (Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by salary desc) as row ,salary from Employee)as temp
where row=2; 
---2nd highest salary
```

Answer (score 0):

**n donated as nth number you want. like : i want second highest so my query will be**
n=2

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

replace n with you number

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n-1,1
```

Answer (score -1):

Query:

```
select 
    ename  
    ,sal  
    ,dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) ranking  
from   emp;
```

output:

```
ENAME   SAL   RANKING
KING    5000    1   
FORD    3000    2  
SCOTT   3000    2  
JONES   2975    3  
CLARK   2850    4  
BLAKE   2850    4  
ALLEN   1600    5
```

Wrap a filter around and pick out the Nth highest salary, say the 4th highest salary.

Query:

```
select *  
from  
(  
  select ename  
        ,sal  
        ,dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) ranking  
  from   emp  
)  
where ranking = 4 -- Replace 4 with any value of N
```

output:

```
ENAME  SAL  RANKING
BLAKE  2850     4  
CLARK  2850     4
```