# Select 5th highest Value without using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I want to fetch 5th highest value without using LIMIT. Here is the code I am trying but it is not working properly. It is showing the 5th lowest value instead of 5th highest value.

```
SELECT a . * FROM user AS a 
WHERE 5 = 
(SELECT count( DISTINCT b.id ) FROM user  AS b WHERE b.id >= a.id ORDER BY a.id DESC)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492357/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary just 4 hours ago!

Comment: Why without using LIMIT?

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
SET @nth := 5;
SELECT
    a.*
FROM jos_modules AS a
WHERE  @nth = ( 
    SELECT 
        COUNT(b.id) 
    FROM user AS b
    WHERE 
        a.id >= b.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a . *
FROM user AS a
WHERE 5 = (
SELECT count( DISTINCT b.id )
FROM user AS b
WHERE a.id >= b.id ORDER BY a.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select a.* , row_number() over (order by id asc) as RANK
from a ) where RANK=5 ;
```

If you are using a Teradata DB , you can use qualify statement :

```
select * from a 
qualify row_number () over(order by id asc)=5;
```