# Selecting the 2nd row in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to select the second row only from the table. From the ClientUserName column.

```
SELECT
    ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts  
FROM 
    #ProxyLog_record  
WHERE
    ClientUserName = (Select top 1 ClientUserName from #ProxyLog_count_2)  
GROUP BY 
    ClientUserName, DestHost 
ORDER BY 
    counts DESC
```

The `(Select top 1 ClientUserName from #ProxyLog_count_2)` shows `top 1` only but I need to get the 2nd data from that table. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Which database are you using?  The solution is rather database dependent.

Comment: You want the *second* row - ordered by what?? By the `ClientUserName`? Or by something else? If you want to have an order (to select the *second* row) - you need to define an order (using `ORDER BY`)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Based on the `TOP (N)` syntax I'm going to guess this is SQL server.

Comment: Why don't you use row_number()? If you can tell me by which column you determine that its the 2nd row, I can write the exact SQL statement for you.

Comment: I am using sql server, I think it's ordered by ClientUserName. If not then it would be counts. Someone put me up to this project.. and i'm not very knowledgeable at it. It's not homework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query to find nth highest salary from salary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-salary-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts  
FROM 
    #ProxyLog_record  
WHERE
    ClientUserName = (    
        ;with cte as 
        (
            select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ClientUserName) as rn, * 
            from #ProxyLog_count_2
        ) 
        select ClientUserName from cte where rn=2    
    )
GROUP BY 
    ClientUserName, DestHost 
ORDER BY 
    counts DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  The "top 1" is selecting a random row from the table, because you have no order by clause.

If you want the second row inserted into the table, the way to do this is to define an auto-incrementing column in the table.  The create table statement should include:

```
create table #ProxyLog_count_2 (
    ProxyLog_Count_2_id int not null identity(1,1),
    ...
)
```

You can then get the second row inserted by using the simple where clause:

```
where ProxyLog_Count_2_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` method like so:

```
WITH c AS (
SELECT
    ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY count(DestHost)) AS rowNum
FROM 
    #ProxyLog_record  
GROUP BY 
    ClientUserName, DestHost 

)
SELECT ClientUserName, DestHost, counts
FROM c
WHERE rowNum = 2
```

(Don't use `count(DestHost) counts` if it's not required, or use another CTE to save counting twice)

Comment: Can you show me how to use that? table name is #ProxyLog_count_2 it's ordered by counts desc. The column name i want is ClientUserName.

Comment: I think it should be ORDER BY ClientUsername?

Comment: Its hard to tell the exact desired output. The example to return the top 1 does not return any particular one since the TOP(1) subquery is not ordered. I just assumed it was count. Switch `ORDER BY count(DestHost)` with with `ORDER BY ClientUserName` to chance the order by which the 2nd option is chosen. (Relational database (e.g. SQL) tables officially have no "order", so there is no such thing as 2nd row unless you specify an order. In fact, I should really have specified more detail in the ORDER BY clause than I gave to make it deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've tried so far...

```
SELECT top 1
    ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts  
FROM 
    #ProxyLog_record  
WHERE
    ClientUserName <> (Select top 1 ClientUserName from #ProxyLog_count_2)  
GROUP BY 
    ClientUserName, DestHost 
ORDER BY 
    counts DESC
```

You could use ROW_NUMBER()...

You could use a cursor...

You could put an identifier in the top row to allow you to filter it out (and then subsequently, select the top 1 again and you'd have it).

Otherwise, if there is something identifiable about the 2nd row (does it have the highest something, or the lowest, or the most recent date, etc.),

Answer (score 0):

Wjy not just select top 2 and take the aecomd row from esult set?

Comment: I know how to select top 2. But how do i Take the second row?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Top 1 a.ClientUserName, a.DestHost, a.counts
FROM
(
SELECT Top 2
    ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts  
FROM 
    #ProxyLog_record  
WHERE
    ClientUserName = (Select top 1 ClientUserName from #ProxyLog_count_2)  
GROUP BY 
    ClientUserName, DestHost 
ORDER BY 
    counts DESC
)
as a
ORDER BY a.Counts ASC
```