# SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table

Tags: mysql

some one help me to find out nth highest salary from the salary table in MYSQL

Comment: @stb, Simply I have a Employee table that having about 100 Employees name and his salary. I want to 2nd or 3rd(i.e nth) highest salary from the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table)

Answer (score 46):

Try this, n would be the nth item you would want to return

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(Salary) FROM table ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n,1
```

Comment: your query would return (n+1)th record from the table, it should be 

`SELECT DISTINCT(Salary) FROM table ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT (n-1),1`

Comment: This return only one record. What if we have 2 or more employee on same salary?

Comment: @Vish The OP asks for the highest salary only, not the employees who have the highest salary. In that case, you can nest this with SELECT Employee FROM table WHERE Salary IN (the answered query.)

Answer (score 34):

If you want to find nth Salary from a table (here n should be any thing like 1st or 2nd or 15th highest Salaries)

**This is the Query for to find nth Salary:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM tblemployee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (n-1)
```

**If you want to find 8th highest salary, query should be :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM tblemployee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7
```

**Note:** OFFSET starts from 0th position, and hence use N-1 rule here

Comment: The best solution that I found here was yours! less messy, no sub queries. only you have to change this `SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM tblemployee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (n -1)` since you also mentioned that offset starts from 0 you should have avoided that

Comment: Thanks!!  for mentioning that offset starts from 0 , got confused earlier :)

Answer (score 18):

To get nth highest salary you need to first sort data by using `ORDER BY` and then select the nth highest record using `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(salary) AS salary
FROM tbl_salary
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (n - 1);
```

Comment: Hi SELECT salary 
FROM tbl_salary
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET n;
                this query is not getting proper output

Comment: hey it should be LIMIT 1 OFFSET (n - 1). try it.

Comment: you need to replace n with some number like 4 for 4th highest salary and don't forget to mark up and accept answer.

Comment: yes I am doing in same way, I replace n with some integer number i.e. 3 or 4 but its not taking minus(-), if I put 4 instead of (4 -1), then error is not displaying but result is displaying of 3rd highest not 4th highest.

Comment: to get 4th highest you need to use LIMIT 1, 3 or to get all records after 4 try LIMIT 0, 4.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  `salary` 
ORDER BY salary DESC 
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1 this worked me to get second highest

Comment: Actually the query in answer is returning (n-1)th record by sorting the results by descending order with respect to salary, but not returning the actual (n-1)th highest salary. You should add Group by salary in the query which will return you exact nth highest salary amount (SELECT salary FROM users group by salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3)

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee Emp1 
WHERE (N-1) = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)) 
    FROM  Employee Emp2 
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

For each record processed by outer query, inner query will be executed and will return how many records has records has salary less than the current salary. If you are looking for second highest salary then your query will stop as soon as inner query will return N-1.

Comment: This is perfect answer for Nth highest salary and also this query return all employee with same salary.

Answer (score 8):

finding the highest salary

```
select MAX(Salary) from Employee;
```

finding the 2nd highest salary

Query-1

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee);
```

Query-2

```
select MAX(Salary) from Employee
WHERE Salary <> (select MAX(Salary) from Employee )
```

finding the nth highest salary

Query-1

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Query-2

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (1) = (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

nth highest salary using the TOP keyword in SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 Salary
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP N Salary
      FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC
      ) AS Emp
ORDER BY Salary
```

Find the nth highest salary in MySQL

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n-1,1
```

Find the nth highest salary in SQL Server

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC OFFSET N-1 ROW(S) 
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Find the nth highest salary in Oracle using rownum

```
select * from (
  select Emp.*, 
row_number() over (order by Salary DESC) rownumb 
from Employee Emp
)
where rownumb = n;  /*n is nth highest salary*/
```

Find the nth highest salary in Oracle using RANK

```
select * FROM (
select EmployeeID, Salary
,rank() over (order by Salary DESC) ranking
from Employee
)
WHERE ranking = N;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we can create the MYSQL function for this.
nth highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE limitv INT;
    SET limitv = N - 1;
  RETURN (
      Select IFNULL(
        (select Distinct Salary from Employee order by Salary Desc limit limitv, 1),
         NULL
      ) as getNthHighestSalary
  );
END
```

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/submissions/

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
select MIN(sal) from salary where sal in 
 (select sal from salary order by sal desc limit 9)
```

Comment: subquery doesn't support limit operation in mysql

Answer (score 2):

if wanna specified nth highest,could use rank method.

To get the third highest, use

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, salary
FROM   tbl,(SELECT @rank := 0) r 
order by salary desc ) m
WHERE rank=3
```

Comment: I don't think that it will work..Unknown column 'rank' in 'where clause'.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one for finding 5th highest salary-

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column name) FROM table ORDER BY (column name) desc LIMIT 4,1
```

for nth salary-

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column name) FROM table ORDER BY (column name) desc LIMIT n-1,1
```

I have tried it on phpmyadmin panel..

Answer (score 2):

```
+-------+--------+
|  name | salary |
+-------+--------+
|   A   | 100    |
|   B   | 200    |
|   C   | 300    |
|   D   | 400    |
|   E   | 500    |
|   F   | 500    |
|   G   | 600    |
+-------+--------+
```

IF YOU WANT TO SELECT ONLY Nth HIGHEST SALARY THEN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET N-1;
```

IF YOU WANT TO SELECT ALL EMPLOYEE WHO GETTING Nth HIGHEST SALARY THEN:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE salary = (
   SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET N-1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM employe e1 WHERE n-1 = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.salary)) FROM employe e2 WHERE e2.salary > e1.salary) 

    Where n = highest number of salary like 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting all the records first, do consume a lot of  time (Imagine if the table contains millions of records). 
However, the trick is to do an improved linear-search.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)
    FROM  Employee Emp2
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary LIMIT N))
```

Here, as soon as inner query finds n distinct salary values greater than outer query's salary, it returns the result to outer query.

Mysql have clearly mentioned about this optimization at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html

The above query can also be written as,

```
SELECT * FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
    FROM  Employee Emp2
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary LIMIT N)
```

Again, if the queries are as simple as just running on single table and needed for informational purposes only, then you could limit the outermost query to return 1 record and run a separate query by placing the nth highest salary in where clause

Thanks to Abishek Kulkarni's solution, on which this optimization is suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(column_name) from table_name order by column_name desc limit (n-1),1;
```

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table**(100% true)

SELECT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT N-1,1;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name)
  FROM table_name 
  ORDER BY column_name DESC limit N-1,1;
```

where N represents the nth highest salary ..

Third highest salary :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name)
 FROM table_name 
 ORDER BY column_name DESC limit 2,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query to get the nth highest record is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        table_name
    ORDER BY column_name ASC
    LIMIT N) AS tbl
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

It's simple and easy to understand

Comment: ASC and DESC should be the other way around. And add "distinct" in the select statement in tb1 in case there are some ties. Otherwise, I love this answer.

Comment: This will not work in Mysql 5.7 as LIMIT is not allowed in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

For 4th highest salary:

select min(salary) from (select distinct salary from hibernatepractice.employee e order by salary desc limit 4) as e1;

For n th highest salary:

select min(salary) from (select distinct salary from hibernatepractice.employee e order by salary desc limit n) as e1;

Answer (score 0):

This will work To find the **nth maximum number**

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * from (SELECT TOP  nth_largest_no * FROM Products Order by price desc) ORDER BY price asc;
```

For Fifth Largest number

```
SELECT 
  TOP 1 *  from (SELECT TOP  5 * FROM Products Order by price desc) ORDER BY price asc;
```

Comment: There is no TOP keyword in MySQL.
Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql.

Answer (score 0):

**This is salary table**

[image]

```
SELECT  amount FROM  salary 
GROUP by amount
ORDER BY  amount DESC 
LIMIT n-1 , 1
```

**Or**

```
SELECT DISTINCT amount
FROM  salary 
ORDER BY  amount DESC 
LIMIT n-1 , 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get 2nd highest salary:

```
SELECT   salary 
FROM     [employees] 
ORDER BY salary DESC 
offset   1 rows 
FETCH next 1 rows only
```

To get Nth highest salary:

```
SELECT   salary 
FROM     [employees] 
ORDER BY salary DESC 
offset   **n-1** rows 
FETCH next 1 rows only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @cnt=0; 
SELECT s.* 
FROM   (SELECT ( @cnt := @cnt + 1 ) AS rank, 
               a.* 
        FROM   one AS a 
        ORDER  BY a.salary DESC) AS s 
WHERE  s.rank = '3';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @cnt=0;
select s.* from (SELECT  (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank,a.* FROM one as a  order by a.salary DESC) as s WHERE s.rank='3';
```

=>this for 3rd highest salary.
 for nth replace 3 value. for example 5th highest:

```
set @cnt=0;
select s.* from (SELECT  (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank,a.* FROM one as a  order by a.salary DESC) as s WHERE s.rank='5';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT salary ORDER BY salary DESC),',',3),',',-1) from employees
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer. I suppose that it will be formatted properly as code by adding 4 blanks in front of your code lines. Just let me give you one hint: It's always good to add some information beside your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be table `salaries` containing

```
+----------+--------+--------+
| emp      | salary | deptno |
+----------+--------+--------+
| ep1      |     10 | dp1    |
| ep2      |     20 | dp2    |
| ep3      |     30 | dp2    |
| ep4      |     40 | dp1    |
| ep5      |     50 | dp1    |
| ep6      |     60 | dp3    |
| ep7      |     70 | dp3    |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

By Nested Queries: (where you can change offset 0/1/2... for first, second and third... place respectively)

```
 select
      *
    from
      salaries as t1 
    where 
      t1.salary = (select 
                   salary
                 from 
                   salaries
                 where 
                 salaries.deptno = t1.deptno ORDER by salary desc limit 1 offset 1);
```

or might be by creating rank: (where you can change rank= 1/2/3... for first, second and third... place respectively)

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
select * from 
(SELECT
  s.*, 
  CASE 
      WHEN @prev_value = deptno THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
      WHEN @prev_value := deptno THEN @rank_count := 1 
      ELSE @rank_count := 1 
  END as rank
FROM salaries s
ORDER BY deptno, salary desc) as t
having t.rank = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Procedure for this query

here `getHighestSalary` procedure, reports the nth highest salary from the Employee table. If there is no nth highest salary, the query should report null.

first, create table

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
salary INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

next, create PROCEDURE

```
DELIMITER // 
 CREATE PROCEDURE getHighestSalary(emp_id int)
 BEGIN
    select ifnull((select salary from employee where id = emp_id order by salary desc), null) as getNthHighestSalary;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

and last, call the getHighestSalary procedure with n value

```
call getHighestSalary(2); -- 200
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all the records of the employees who has third highest salary then you can use this `sql` query:

Table name: salary

```
select * from salary where salary = 
(select distinct salary from salary order by salary desc limit 2,1)
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain why this answer is down voted?