# SQL query to find third highest salary in company

Tags: sql

I need to write a query that will return the third highest salaried employee in the company.

I was trying to accomplish this with subqueries, but could not get the answer.  My attempts are below:

```
select Max(salary)
from employees
where Salary not in

 (select Max(salary)
from employees
where Salary not in 

(select Max(salary)
from employees));
```

My thought was that I could use 2 subqueries to elimitate the first and second highest salaries.  Then I could simply select the `MAX()` salary that is remaining.  Is this a good option, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: i am a  novice please sum1 explain how limit works and please answer my question how many subquery chain is permitted?

Comment: I don't see any `SUM` calls in there. The only aggregation is `MAX`. Did you copy the entirety of your query?

Comment: @user3120566 `LIMIT` does exactly what you would expect, it only returns as many rows as you tell it. So `LIMIT 3` only returns 3 rows. As for your subqueries refer to my answer.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: If you have a hierarchy tree of your company, don't need a complicated query, just return the CEO's salary :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table)

Answer (score 76):

The most simple way that should work in any database is to do following:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

Which orders employees by salary and then tells db to return a single result (1 in LIMIT) counting from third row in result set (2 in OFFSET). It may be `OFFSET 3` if your DB counts result rows from 1 and not from 0.

This example should work in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

**Edit:**

But there's a catch if you only want the 3rd highest DISTINCT salary. Than you should add the `DISTINCT` keyword.

In case of salary list: 100, 90, 90, 80, 70.
In the above query it will produce the 3rd highest salary which is 90. But if you mean the 3rd distinct which is 80 than you should use

```
SELECT DISTINCT `salary` FROM `employee` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

But there's a catch, this will return you only 1 column which is `Salary`, because in order to operate the distinction operation, DISTINCT can only operate on a specific set of columns.
This means we should add another wrapping query to extract the employees(There can be multiple) that matches that result. Thus I added `LIMIT 1` at the end.

```
SELECT *
FROM `employee`
WHERE
    `Salary` = (SELECT DISTINCT `Salary`
        FROM `employee`
        ORDER BY `salary` DESC
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
     )
LIMIT 1;
```

Examples can be found [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kypbSttwBuXHzC7AFEfmMJ/1)

Comment: Orel Eraki this query will not return correct result if salaries are not unique. Have you solution for that also?

Comment: If salaries are not unique then we have to use group by. Following query will work in that case
select salary  from <table_name> group by salary order by salary desc limit 1 offset 2;

Comment: @SonyKhan, `DISTINCT` will probably be a faster option. I'll add it later, Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

You can get the third highest salary by using limit , by using TOP keyword and sub-query

1. `TOP` keyword

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 salary 
   FROM 
       (SELECT TOP 3 salary 
        FROM Table_Name 
        ORDER BY salary DESC) AS Comp 
   ORDER BY salary ASC
   ```
2. limit

   ```
   SELECT salary 
   FROM Table_Name 
   ORDER BY salary DESC 
   LIMIT 2, 1
   ```
3. by subquery

   ```
   SELECT salary  
   FROM 
       (SELECT salary 
        FROM Table_Name 
        ORDER BY salary DESC 
        LIMIT 3) AS Comp 
   ORDER BY salary 
   LIMIT 1;
   ```

I think anyone of these help you.

Answer (score 17):

You may try (if MySQL):

```
SELECT salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2, 1;
```

This query returns one row after skipping two rows.

You may also want to return distinct salary. For example, if you have 20,20,10 and 5 then 5 is the third highest salary. To do so, add `DISTINCT` to the above query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2, 1;
```

Comment: i am a  novice please sum1 explain how limit works and please answer my question how many subquery chain is permitted?

Comment: LIMIT 1,2 means that you want 1 row after have skipped 2 rows.

Comment: In this case, you need no subqueries.

Comment: @Mihai
are you sure it is `LIMIT 1, 2` 
shouldn't it be `LIMIT 2, 1`    (2 rows skipped and 1 row returned?)
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: @GauravJain You are correct,but thats not my answer,I just edited it.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT Max(salary) 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  salary < (SELECT Max(salary) 
                 FROM   employee 
                 WHERE  salary NOT IN(SELECT Max(salary) 
                                      FROM   employee))
```

hope this helped you

Answer (score 6):

If SQL Server this could work

```
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM
   (SELECT TOP (3) salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC) T
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

As for your number of subqueries question goes it depends on your language. Check this for more information

[Is there a nesting limit for correlated subqueries in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233910/is-there-a-nesting-limit-for-correlated-subqueries-in-oracle)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel This is for SQL Server which does not support `LIMIT` OP didn't state what language.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel `TOP` is fairly close to `LIMIT` so using it instead isn't that much of a hassle. Can you really expect all languages, no matter what the subject matter is, to have the same functions?

Answer (score 5):

SELECT `id`
FROM `tablename`
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 2 , 1

This is only for get 3rd highest value .

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Some DBMS's don't allow you to run several nested queries.  Here is a solution that only uses 1 nested query:

```
SELECT salary
FROM
(
   SELECT salary
   FROM employees
   ORDER BY salary
   LIMIT 3
) as TBL1
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

It should give you the desired result. It first finds the 3 largest salaries, then selects the smallest of the three (or the third one if they are equal). Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/958a3/1)

Comment: i am a  novice please sum1 explain how limit works and please answer my question how many subquery chain is permitted?

Comment: @user3120566 The number of subqueries you can execute depends on which DBMS you are using.  Understand that they will only increase execution time.  The above query first finds the 3 largest salaries, then selects the smallest of the three (or the third one if they are equal).  So this solution uses 1 subquery.

Comment: Why nested query at all?!

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel The OP appeared interested in a solution involving nested queries.  Regardless, this is a valid solution to the question and meets the OP's requirements.

Comment: If the OP has no idea what he's doing and is doing unwise things you will encourage him to? Some on...

Comment: To be perfectly fair, this query is almost exactly as efficient as any of the other solutions here; not to mention much more portable.

Comment: It's not "as efficient" and it makes no sense either on DB which support LIMIT or ones that don't.

Comment: The ordering of 3 tuples is a negligible overhead in this situation IMO.  And I was referencing those solutions specific to MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

**You may use this for all employee with 3rd highest salary:**

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE salary = (
   SELECT DISTINCT(`salary`) FROM `employee` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a very good explanation in

> http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/

This query should give `nth` highest salary

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
    FROM Employee Emp2
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can find the Top nth Salary with this Query.

WITH EMPCTE AS (
SELECT E.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS DENSERANK
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
)
SELECT * FROM EMPCTE WHERE DENSERANK=&NUM

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM `employee` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Salary,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC)
  FROM Employee
)
SELECT salary
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 3
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested query to get that, like below one is explained for the third max salary. Every nested salary is giving you the highest one with the filtered where result and at the end it will return you exact 3rd highest salary irrespective of number of records for the same salary.

```
select * from users where salary < (select max(salary) from users where salary < (select max(salary) from users))  order by salary desc limit 1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks Nico for your guidance. I will take care of that in future and also I edited the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give accurate answer. Follow and give me comments:

```
select top 1 salary from (
select DISTINCT  top 3 salary from Table(table name) order by salary  ) as comp
order by personid salary
```

Answer (score 1):

## in Sql Query you can get nth highest salary

select * from(
select empname, sal, dense_rank()
over(order by sal desc)r from Employee)
where r=&n;

To find to the 2nd highest sal set n = 2

To find 3rd highest sal set n = 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

you can get any order for salary with that:

```
select * from 
(
select salary,row_Number() over (order by salary DESC ) RN 
FROM employees
)s
where RN = 3
```

-- put RN equal to any number of orders.
--for your question put 3

Answer (score 1):

You can find Nth highest salary by making use of just one single query which is very simple to understand:-

> select salary from employees e1 where N-1=(select count(distinct
> salary) from employees e2 where e2.salary>e1.salary);

Here Replace "N" with number(1,2,3,4,5...).This query work properly even when where salaries are duplicate. The simple idea behind this query is that the inner subquery
count how many salaries are greater then (N-1). When we get the count then the cursor will point to that row which is N and it simply returns the salary present in that row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT salary FROM employees e1
       WHERE N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM employees e2
                    WHERE e2.salary > e1.salary)
```

Here, I have solved it with a **correlated nested query**. It is a generalized Query so if you want to print **4th**, **5th**, or any number of highest salary it will work perfectly even if there are any duplicate salaries.

So, what you have to do is simply change the **N** value here. So, in your case, it will be,

```
SELECT salary FROM employees e1
       WHERE 3-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM employees e2
                    WHERE e2.salary > e1.salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM(

SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK()

OVER(ORDER BY salary DESC)r FROM Employee)

WHERE r=&n;

To find the 3rd highest salary set n = 3

Answer (score 1):

**Mysql Query to find third highest salary in company**

```
select Max(payment) from wallets where payment < (select Max(payment) from wallets where payment < (select Max(payment) from wallets));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the third highest salary may be the same the the first highest salary so your current approach wouldn't work.

I would do order the employees by salary and apply a `LIMIT 3` at the end of the SQL query. You'll then have the top three of highest salaries and, thus, you also have the third highest salary (if there is one, a company may have two employees and then you wouldn't have a third highest salary).

Answer (score 0):

For me this query work fine in Mysql 
it will return third max salary from table

SELECT `salary` FROM `users` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;

or

SELECT `salary` FROM `users` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 2,1;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 BILL_AMT Bill_Amt FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 NH_BL_BILL.BILL_AMT FROM NH_BL_BILL ORDER BY BILL_AMT DESC) A 
ORDER BY BILL_AMT ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

select min (salary) from Employee where Salary in (Select Top 3 Salary from Employee order by Salary desc)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(salary) AS max
FROM STAFF
WHERE salary IN
(SELECT salary 
 FROM STAFF
 WHERE salary<(SELECT MAX(salary) AS maxima 
 FROM STAFF
 WHERE salary<
 (SELECT MAX(salary) AS maxima
  FROM STAFF))
GROUP BY salary);
```

I have tried other ways they are not right. This one works.

Comment: THIS ONE ALSO WORKS: SELECT MAX(SALARY) AS MAX FROM STAFF WHERE salary IN (SELECT TOP (3) [salary]
FROM[STAFF] ORDER BY salary ASC)

Answer (score 0):

for oracle it goes like this:

```
select salary from employee where rownnum<=3 order by salary desc
minus
select salary from employee where rownnum<=2 order by salary desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL-Server implementation of this will be:

```
SELECT SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a MYSQL query.

Explanation: The subquery returns top 3 salaries. From the returned result, we select the minimum salary, which is the 3rd highest salary.

```
SELECT MIN(Salary)
FROM (
    SELECT Salary
    FROM Employees
    ORDER BY Salary DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS TopThreeSalary;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with Oracle db.

```
select SAL from ( SELECT DISTINCT SAL FROM EMP ORDER BY SAL DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY ) ORDER BY SAL  ASC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM maintable_B7E8K
order by Salary
desc limit 1 offset 2;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: The above feedback from @novonimo is _especially_ important when there's already an answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Comment: And in fact the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690671/3744182) says to do ```SELECT * FROM (table name) ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;``` so this appears to be functionally a duplicate answer. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29988142)

Answer (score 0):

--Oracle SQL

`with temp as (
select distinct salary  from HR.EMPLOYEES
order by SALARY desc
)
select min(temp.salary) from temp
where rownum <= 3;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can find the third most salary with this query:

```
SELECT min(salary) 
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE salary IN (SELECT TOP(3) salary 
                 FROM tblEmployee 
                 ORDER BY salary DESC)
```