# find the N-th largest element in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Wondering how to write a SQL function to find the N-th largest element in a table, and if no N-th largest element, return Null.

Using MySQL/MySQL workbench.

BTW, my question is different from the N-th highest salary question since I have one additional requirement, which is return Null if N-th largest element does not exist. Any thoughts are appreciated.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table)

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra, it is not the same. I have one additional requirement, which is return Null if N-th largest element does not exist. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: How do you want elements of equal value handled?

Comment: @NickBailey, good question. In normal sense, suppose salary for 5 employee are, 300, 200, 200, 100, 100, and what do you think is the 2nd and 3rd highest?

Comment: Well, there isn't really a normal sense, that's why I asked you to specify...

Comment: How about I want to treat as unique, 2nd and 3rd highest is 200 and 100 (other than 200, 200 which we honor duplicate).

Comment: @NickBailey, my current problem is, if in my case, I want to select the 6th largest element, I want to return Null other than nothing. You can find examples in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table) returns nothing other than Null if N-th highest does not exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  ORDER BY value DESC
  LIMIT 1
  OFFSET N -- Set your value for N here, N being 0-based
) t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT null -- This will guarantee that you have at least one row
) t2
ON TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no instance where I would want to do this...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 9 THEN x.i ELSE NULL END i 
  FROM ints x 
  JOIN ints y 
    ON y.i <= x.i 
 GROUP 
    BY x.i 
 ORDER 
    BY i DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    8 |
+------+

SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 11 THEN x.i ELSE NULL END i 
  FROM ints x 
  JOIN ints y 
    ON y.i <= x.i 
 GROUP 
    BY x.i 
 ORDER 
    BY i DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
SELECT *from Employee_Test_salary

go

with emplsal as(
 SELECT Emp_Sal ,DENSE_RANK() over (order by Emp_Sal desc) as rownumber
 from Employee_Test_salary  
)
select top 1 Emp_Sal from emplsal where emplsal.rownumber =N
```