# return Null other than empty in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For a SQL select query, if there is no matched result, nothing will be returned, and if I want to return Null other than nothing when there is no matched result, is there any good solutions which is generalize too all kinds of select query?

I am using MySQL/MySQL Workbench.

For example, query could be,

```
select * from Student
where score > 90
order by score
limit 100, 1
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Add your query please.

Comment: @Jens, added. Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: not clear enough - do you also want to return records with null scores ?

Comment: @amdixon, suppose there is no record in Student table, the query will return nothing. I want it to return Null, similar to built-in SQL function, always return something. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why, because I think its crazy.

Comment: @RohitGupta, why? I want to wrap some query in a function, and making sure the function returns something, even if Null, benefit is align with how SQL built-in function like Max is doing -- always return something, even if Null. :)

Comment: select *, score > 90 from Student
order by score
limit 100, 1

Comment: @Strawberry, seems not working for me?

Comment: 'Not working' is a meaningless concept

Comment: [You have already asked this question (in different words) here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32409805/521799).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this in Oracle. Should work in mysql also.

```
      select 
      case when 0=
      (      --your query with count(*)
              select count(*) from Student
              where score > 90
              order by score
              limit 100, 1
      ) 
      then null 
      else 1 
      end result 
      from dual
```

Comment: when you use else 1? I need to return the real select query returned value other than 1. :)

Comment: BTW, what is dual and result in your code? Thanks.

Comment: dual is dummy table. result is alias of column which will hold this null/1 value.

    you can use above query in a proc and return null if result is 0. and if it is 1, then put the select statement in a variable and execute it to get result

Comment: does it mean I need to execute the query twice -- first time just to calculate count and 2nd time to get the actual result if count is not zero? Thanks.